# Json_encode accents issue

Tags: php, android, json

i'm trying to parsing with json a website to see the result of a query in my application.. I have a problem. I used `json_encode` to display the results because sometimes i displayed a `null` string. I use this part of code

```
$json = array(); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){ 
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$json['oscar'][]=$row; 

$json[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row); 
} 
} 

mysql_close($con); 
echo json_encode($json);
```

With this, i can display something but the accents are wrong; for example:

```
Mor\u00ec would be Morì
```

etc etc. Here you can see http://www.oscarilfilm.com/newjson.php . How can i fix the problem?

Comment: Does your database store the values with utf8-encoding?

Comment: I'm using wordpress and PhpMyAdmin so to be honest i don't know.. How can i check? And, in case, fix?

Comment: EDIT: i found this line in the wp-config.php file: `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); `

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the part where you transform the entire content of the row into 'UTF-8'?

Comment: The way characters are shown it seems like a encoding issue. The database seems to be in UTF8 already, so translating it once more seems out of place...

Comment: Yeah, you're right but if i comment or remove that part the result is null. I don't know why.. I have something like `{"oscar":[{"id":"39","post_title":"Oscar","post_content":null}]`

Comment: I get it now, you database is in UTF8, but the content you input is not. Try the solution I posted bellow, with the utf8 encode.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the extra argument of PHP encode? For example:

```
$json = array(); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){ 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        $json['oscar'][]=$row; 
        $json[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row); 
    } 
} 

mysql_close($con); 
echo json_encode($json);
```

Changed to this:

```
$json = array(); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){ 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        $json['oscar'][]=$row; 
        $json[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row); 
    } 
} 

mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

As shown on this [page](http://pt1.php.net/json_encode).

EDIT: To view the response in UTF-8 you can try adding this line to the very begining of your page:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Comment: Nope, "echo json_encode($json);" transforms into:
"echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);"

Comment: I edited the answer to make it easier to understand.

Comment: mmh `Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long..`

Comment: I changed the php version. Now i have the 5.4 and i get no errors.. But now the accents are all `Ã`. :(

Comment: This makes thing easier... Your browser displays the default encoding (in your case "ISO-8859-1" which is the default encoding for windows.) As this is only json dump, you haven't set any meta tag to select a default encoding, and as such your browser displays it in ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. Don't worry if program code reads it it should be OK. Just to make sure try changing your encoding to UTF-8. if you tell me the browser you use I can even tell you how to do that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49162/discussion-between-hristo-valkanov-and-end-game)